# Avoid duplicate values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My Table `table1` looks like this:

```
 no    name

 1      C_GT_2013-2014,C_GT_AcMaster,C_GT_Master
 1      C_GT_2014-2015,C_GT_AcMaster,C_GT_Master
 2      C_TGYY_2013-2014,G_New_AcMaster,G_New_Master
 2      C_TGYY_2014-2015,G_New_AcMaster,G_New_Master
 3      C_TGYN_2013-2014,G_ACYMAN_AcMaster,C_TGYN_Master
 3      C_TGYN_2014-2015,G_ACYMAN_AcMaster,C_TGYN_Master
 4      C_TGNY_2013-2014,C_TGNY_AcMaster,G_ACNMAY_Master
 4      C_TGNY_2014-2015,C_TGNY_AcMaster,G_ACNMAY_Master
 5      C_GYY_2013-2014,G_New_AcMaster,G_New_Master
 6      C_DD_2013-2014,C_DD_AcMaster,G_ACNMAY_Master
 7      C_YN_2013-2014,G_ACYMAN_AcMaster,C_YN_Master
```

I want to retrieve the value without duplicate `no` and split the `name` using ","  so I tried like this:

```
select (string_to_array(name,','))[3] as master
      ,(string_to_array(name,','))[2] as acmaster
      ,string_agg((string_to_array(name,','))[1],',') as trans
      ,no
 from table t
 where no in (2,3,4,6,7)
 group by (string_to_array(schemaname,','))[3]
        , (string_to_array(schemaname,','))[2]
        , no
 order by no
```

But it return no duplicate. I want to get the value

1. No duplicate in `no` column
2. Name have same `no`. It merage using ',' like this (`no 1   name with split(',') C_GT_2013-2014,C_GT_2014-2015`)

I am using **Postgresql 9.3**.

My result would be:

I want to split Name into three columns which word have master its comes to Master column, Which word have its Comes to AcMaster, Others Comes to Trans With out No duplicate

```
 Master            AcMaster                  Trans                                   No

 G_New_Master     G_New_AcMaster             C_TGYY_2013-2014,C_TGYY_2014-2015        1
 C_TGYN_Master,   G_ACYMAN_AcMaster          C_TGYN_2014-2015,C_TGYN_2013-2014,       2
 C_YN_Master                                             C_YN_2013-2014    

 G_ACNMAY_Master  C_DD_AcMaster,              C_DD_2013-2014                          3
                  C_TGNY_AcMaster             C_TGNY_2013-2014,C_TGNY_2014-2015
```

Comment: Please show the desired results for the data you have posted.

Comment: . . That didn't help.  What is the relationship between the columns and values in your results and the columns and values in the original table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  `I want to split Name into three columns which word have master its comes to Master column, Which word have its Comes to AcMaster, Others Comes to Trans With out No duplicate`

Comment: I think you did not format correctly your desired output. i did not understand what do you want too!

Comment: Your ultimate goal should be to normalize the database schema and sidestep these (and many other) kinds of problems altogether. By putting several values in the same field, you are violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF.

Comment: Your query (after some cleaning up) seems to do what you want already: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03cf4/2 What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yet another case of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17808/7788 . Please fix your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query :

```
select no,
string_agg(case when name like '%\_Master' escape '\' then name end, ','),
string_agg(case when name like '%\_AcMaster' escape '\' then name end, ','),
string_agg(case when (name not like '%\_Master' and name not like '%\_AcMaster' escape '\') then name end, ',')
from
(select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[1] as name
from   table1
union
select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[2] as name
from   table1
union
select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[3] as name
from   table1) t
where no in (2,3,4,6,7)
group by no
order by no
```

This query result is :

```
no  Master              AcMaster        Trans

2   G_New_Master        G_New_AcMaster      C_TGYY_2014-2015,C_TGYY_2013-2014
3   C_TGYN_Master       G_ACYMAN_AcMaster   C_TGYN_2014-2015,C_TGYN_2013-2014
4   G_ACNMAY_Master     C_TGNY_AcMaster     C_TGNY_2013-2014,C_TGNY_2014-2015
6   G_ACNMAY_Master     C_DD_AcMaster       C_DD_2013-2014
7   C_YN_Master         G_ACYMAN_AcMaster   C_YN_2013-2014
```

And now some explanations :

1- I flatten the your table :

```
(select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[1] as name
from   table1
union
select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[2] as name
from   table1
union
select no, (string_to_array(name,','))[3] as name
from   table1)
```

so I can have results like this :

```
4   G_ACNMAY_Master
1   C_GT_Master
3   G_ACYMAN_AcMaster
1   C_GT_2013-2014
2   G_New_Master
2   G_New_AcMaster
1   C_GT_2014-2015
...
```

2- I select the 3 required columns :

```
case when name like '%\_Master' escape '\' then name end -- Master
case when name like '%\_AcMaster' escape '\' then name end -- AcMaster
case when (name not like '%\_Master' and name not like '%\_AcMaster' escape '\') then name end -- Trans
```

getting the following result :

```
2   G_New_Master
2                                       C_TGYY_2014-2015
2                   G_New_AcMaster
2                                       C_TGYY_2013-2014
3                                       C_TGYN_2014-2015
...
```

3- After that I aggregate the result using the string_agg function grouping by `no` :

```
string_agg(case when name like '%\_Master' escape '\' then name end, ',')
```

Comment: That is the most incredibly convoluted way of manipulating data I've ever seen.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sure it's convoluted but I haven't found another way to do this :)

Comment: @CraigRinger I have updated my answer, do you still found it convoluted :)